# about the percentile of $f(X)$

Tags: probability

Is the, say $90\%$, percentile of $X$ the same as the $90\%$ percentile of $aX+b$, where $a, b$ are constant?

I mean, to calculate the $90\%$ percentile of $X$, can I use the central limit law to calculate the $90\%$ percentile of $Y=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ instead of X?

Is the $90\%$ percentile of $f(X)$ always the same as $X$? (or iff $f(\cdot)$ is a linear function?)

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you're asking whether the 90th percentile of the distribution of $Y=aX+b$ is achieved at $ax^{\star} + b$ where $x^{\star}$ is the 90th percentile of the distribution of $X$ and, as long as $a > 0$, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking (exactly for random variables $W$ with continuous distribution) a $90$-th percentile of $W$ is a number $k$ (usually unique) such that $P(W \le k)=0.9$.

Let $\sigma$ be any **positive** constant, let $\mu$ be a constant. Let $Y=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$.  Let $k$ be "the" $90$-th percentile of $Y$.
Then 
$$0.9=P(Y \le k)=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} \le k\right)=P(X \le \sigma k+\mu).$$
So $\sigma k+\mu$ is the $90$-th percentile of $X$.  Conversely, if $d$ is the $90$-th percentile of $X$, similar reasoning shows that $\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma}$ is the $90$-th percentile of $Y$.

**Comment:** The idea generalizes.  If $f$ is a strictly  **increasing** function, we can go back and forth between the $p$-th percentile of $X$ and the $p$-th percentile of $f(X)$ by doing what comes naturally. For such an $f$, the number $k$ is a $p$-th percentile of $X$ if and only if $f(k)$ is a $p$-th percentile of $f(X)$. So your intuition was right.  The actual *expression* you used was not quite right, the percentiles are not the *same*, but they are related in the "natural" way.  Of course things can, and usually  do break down for functions $f$ that are not everywhere increasing.

Comment: OK, now I understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

Um, no. The 90% percentile of $aX+b$ is $a($90% of $X)+b$, assuming that $a>0$.

So if you find the 90% percentile of $aX+b$ you have to subtract $b$ and divide by $a$ in order to find the 90% percentile of $X$.

Comment: OK, thank you so much!